# Linker error (LNK2019) on programming dll wrappers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, lnk2019

I’m trying to use an external .dll for a camera in my c++ project. I use Visual Studio 2010.
I have 3 files: The uEye.h file in /include of my project folder, which I included under Properties…C/C++…additional_include_directories and via #include "include/uEye.h".

Then the uEye_api_64.lib in the /lib folder of my project. I added the path under Properties…Linker…General…Additional_Library_Directories and added uEye_api_64.lib under Properties…Linker…Input…Additional_Dependencies.

And finally the uEye_api_64.dll, which I put to the .cpp files in my project folder.
Now I’m trying to use the functions provided by the DLL, for Example is_ExitCamera(), but upon building I get the Linker Error

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__is_ExitCamera referenced in
>   function …

I have searched numerous forum posts but can’t find out what I did wrong.

Source code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "include/uEye.h"
#include "MeasurementAgents_CameraAbstraction.h"
#include <iostream>

UINT nDeviceID = 1;
HIDS hCAM = 0;

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_MeasurementAgents_CameraAbstraction_CamDisconnect
  (JNIEnv *, jclass){
       int nRet = is_ExitCamera(hCAM);
       if(nRet==IS_SUCCESS){
             return true;
       }else{
             std::cout << nRet;
             return false;
       }
}
```

Comment: it is possible that library and your project built with different Runtime Library Settings (Project Options -, C/C++ -> Code Generation -. Runtime Library). The rule here is to use the same runtime library for all your project parts.

Comment: Where is your third-party dll placed?

Comment: @vard, Thanks for your fast response, I tried all 4 available settings but all gave the same error (multi-threaded even more).

Comment: @vard, the uEye_api_64.dll is located in the project folder and in the windows/system32 folder.

Comment: fact that you got error on linking step means that .lib isn't appropriate. Maybe you should set some preprocessor macro for your project, look in your 3rd party library documentaion.

Comment: have you defined macro _IDS_EXPORT or _FALC_EXPORT?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by that, I can’t find anything in the documentation or the example proramms. But _IDS_EXPORT and _FALC_EXPORT are defined in the uEye.h file which I included:
#if defined (_MSC_VER) || defined (__BORLANDC__) || defined (_WIN32_WCE)
  #if defined (_PURE_C) && !defined (_IDS_EXPORT) && !defined (_FALC_EXPORT)
    #define IDSEXP     extern  __declspec(dllimport) INT __cdecl
    #define IDSEXPUL   extern  __declspec(dllimport) ULONG __cdecl
  #elif defined (__STDC__) && !defined (_IDS_EXPORT) && !defined (_FALC_EXPORT)

Comment: #define IDSEXP   extern  __declspec(dllimport) INT __cdecl
    #define IDSEXPUL extern  __declspec(dllimport) ULONG __cdecl
  #elif !defined (_IDS_EXPORT) && !defined (_FALC_EXPORT)   // using the DLL, not creating one
    #define IDSEXP   extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) INT __cdecl
    #define IDSEXPUL extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) ULONG __cdecl
  #elif defined (_IDS_VBSTD) || defined (_FALC_VBSTD)     // for creating stdcall dll
 #define IDSEXP    extern __declspec(dllexport) INT __stdcall
    #define IDSEXPUL  extern __declspec(dllexport) ULONG __stdcall

Comment: #else            // for creating cdecl dll
    #define IDSEXP    extern  __declspec(dllexport) INT __cdecl
    #define IDSEXPUL  extern  __declspec(dllexport) ULONG __cdecl
  #endif
#elif !defined (_IDS_EXPORT) && !defined (_FALC_EXPORT)  // using the DLL, not creating one
  #define IDSEXP    extern  __declspec(dllimport) INT __cdecl
  #define IDSEXPUL  extern  __declspec(dllimport) ULONG __cdecl
#endif